# SmartGit -- Move tag up?

Tags: git, smartgit

I use SmartGit and I'm maintaining two branches that often need to be merged together (Master and branch A).  My normal process is to switch to A, merge in master, push, switch to Master, merge in A, push.

Is there a way to do this quicker in SmartGit?  I'd like to do something like 1) switch to A, merge Master, tell Master to update itself to A.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, absolutely! First, you should create a merge commit, by switching to `A` and merging `master` in, specifying **Merge-commit** mode. Now `A` and `HEAD` both point to the merge commit, while `master` points to the last pre-merge commit to `master`; you are on a branch `A`.

Then you **Check Out** (*Ctrl+G* by default) the merge commit, using `master` as a new local branch and forcing overwrite. That way, `master` branch pointer moves to the merge commit and you switch to it.

Comment: Didn't work... After selecting "Force overwrite", it added a new branch that is `origin/master:<mybranch>`, and `origin/<mybranch>` is stuck below.